# Script to convert List of object to string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list as follows:

```
caseStatusList: Array(3)
0: {id: 2, descr: "EEO"}
1: {id: 3, descr: "EE"}
2: {id: 7, descr: "E"}
```

I want to use a typescript function to convert this caseStatusList to a string seperated by comma as follows:

```
String caseStatusList = EEO,EE,E
```

I want to do this in typescript in angular.ts file. What is the best way to do ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I used StringBuilder with an append but what to use StringUtils or Streams

Comment: If you want a typescript function, then why you used StringBuilder?

Comment: I was trying to convert in Java and bring it to UI . Then thought of doing it in UI itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
caseStatusList.map(item => item.descr).join(',')
```